# Seamless Single Sign on: How to Security harden the AZUREADSSOACC computer account

Tags: azure, office365, single-sign-on, seamless-login

When implementing the Seamless Single Sign-On according the the Microsoft documentation, there is following important notice:

> Important
> The AZUREADSSOACC computer account needs to be strongly protected for security reasons. Only Domain Admins should be able to manage the computer account. Ensure that Kerberos delegation on the computer account is disabled, and that no other account in Active Directory has delegation permissions on the AZUREADSSOACC computer account.. Store the computer account in an Organization Unit (OU) where they are safe from accidental deletions and where only Domain Admins have access. The Kerberos decryption key on the computer account should also be treated as sensitive. We highly recommend that you roll over the Kerberos decryption key of the AZUREADSSOACC computer account at least every 30 days.

What does this explicitly mean for the object Security Tab (Advanced Security Settings)? Which objects should have which permissions. For example upon default creation, the principal "Everyone" has the "change password" permission. That can't be right...

Any help is appreciated.

SOURCE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-how-it-works

What Security permissions should be set for this object?